# How long does a Booster Trooper guest pass last?

Tags: steam, booster-trooper

I just added Booster Trooper to my library on Steam, and received six guest passes. Each pass says

> This pass only gives you access to the full version of this game for a limited time period.

but doesn't say how long that limited time period is. Does anyone know?

Comment: I got some of these from a bundle recently as well.  Would also like to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Booster Trooper guest pass allows your guest to play Booster Trooper for 48 hours before it expires [as stated by DNS employee, Dei, on the Steam forums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1258400):

> Each exisiting and future copy of Booster Trooper now includes 6 guest passes to give away to your friends. 
>   They are valid fore 2 days.